# Background color hides border

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a set of cards that show some baseball player stats on them.  They are floated next to each other in a 4-column layout.  A few of the rows within the card have a background color of #EEEEEE.  When viewing the output, the cards display fine, but when I print them, the print preview and subsequent print to PDF (CutePDF Writer) option both fail to render the borders for any row that contain the aforementioned background color.

I have confirmed this by removing the background color and the missing boarders reappear.  Here's my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/q2pczg5h/

Here is the CSS in question:

```
.clear-fix {
    clear:both;
}


/* CARD STYLES */
#card-container {
    width:705px; 
}

.card-group, .new-page{
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.card *
{
    font-family:arial;
}

.card {
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-top:1px solid black;

    width:175px;
    float:left;
}
.first-name {
    font-size:10pt;
    display:inline;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.last-name {
    display:inline;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10pt;
}
.team-name {
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
}

.player-name {
    text-align:center;
    background:#EEEEEE;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-size:12pt;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.position {
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
}
.bats {
    float:right;
    font-size:8pt;
}
.card-row {
    padding:5px;
}

.header .column {
    font-weight:bold;
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    font-size:8pt;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}

.data .column {
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    font-size:8pt;
    padding:5px 0 10px 0;
}

.advanced-hitting {
    padding:10px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

Once you run it, try to print and you'll see the behavior I have described.

I have tried messing with the floats, changing the background-color, different combinations of borders, and even "overflow:hidden" as described in another SO post.  I'm sure this is something simple, but nothing I've tried seems to render these borders.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You have several `display: none` declarations in your `@media print`. Is this intentional? None of the `@media print` selectors target anything in your fiddle, so I'm assuming they're targeting additional code not included. This could be responsible for the print issues.

Comment: The CSS in question has no border?

Comment: Side notes: If there was ever a time to use a `table` it's probably now. The varying CSS syntax is pretty painful in your fiddle. There isn't a `border: none` property - / so, it should be 0 or 0px instead.

Comment: I think you're right. I try to avoid tables but in this case the markup gets a little unwieldy. As for the display none, that is some extra code I didn't need to include. I only included that chick because I needed to include code along with my fine as a requirement. Maybe I should have just posted the whole css.

Comment: I added my full CSS to the top post.  Removing the print styles didn't have an affect.

Comment: Have you actually printed this? Because I think it will be ok on paper. The print preview fits the whole thing so it can display all the info to you therefore messing up a bit with the displayed styles but not changing them in practice. For me, after I did 2 tabs over the "+" button so I can see a better scale - all the borders displayed correctly while initially they were messed up on the left side. If I continue zooming eventually I get double borders etc. It's browsers issue present in (at least) chrome and firefox.

Comment: Samuil, you're right it does actually print fine.  The strange thing is that when I print to PDF using CutePDF Writer, it still shows the missing borders, but prints correctly.  When I zoom in at 800% inside acrobad reader, it does still show some weirdness around the borders...see image:

https://i.imgur.com/IsylK7R.png

Comment: *For fun*, I took a stab at how I'd write the markup for this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/q2pczg5h/3/

Comment: Very cool, I'll check it out.  I'm a back-end developer with a very strong FE team that perhaps I rely on too much.  Hence, I take on these small projects to try and get better.  I appreciate the alternative viewpoint you've provided.

Comment: I've only dealt with print styles a little - but I suggest breaking this down a bit first... how about a box, - with a border... does that print the way you want? How about - a box without a border... etc... Good Luck!  : )

Comment: That's my standard trick when all else fails. I broke it down to a pretty simple level and it still has the same behavior. Tha KS for your help!